# Pandas - Delete rows with two or more NaN values in dataframe

Tags: numpy, pandas

I want to delete column values that contain too many NaN values; specifically: 2 or more. 
I have a dataframe with column which looks like this. The below column had 40 rows . I want to remove NaN values from 19th row (after 17.9 value).

```
AvgWS

0.12  
1  
2.04  
3.01  
3.99  
5  
6  
7  
7.99  
9  
10  
10.98  
11.99  
13  
13.93  
14.99  
15.98  
NaN  
17.9  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN  
NaN
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `isnull()` on the column, this will return a series with boolean values, you then cast this to `int`, the `True` values become `1` and `False` becomes `0` and then call `cumsum()`, we then filter the df where the cumumlative sum is less than 2 which equates to the point where the `NaN` count becomes greater than 2:

```
In [110]:

df[df['AvgWS'].isnull().astype(int).cumsum() < 2]
Out[110]:
    AvgWS
0    0.12
1    1.00
2    2.04
3    3.01
4    3.99
5    5.00
6    6.00
7    7.00
8    7.99
9    9.00
10  10.00
11  10.98
12  11.99
13  13.00
14  13.93
15  14.99
16  15.98
17    NaN
18  17.90
```